# Issues moving file with WinSCP in a WebJob

Tags: c#, sftp, azure-webjobs, winscp, winscp-net

I have some issues to move file from a repository to another one in a webjob. 
I use the command `_session.MoveFile("mypathsource","mypathdestination")`. 
My webjob is triggered every 10 minutes.

When I deploy my webjob, it moves the file but after few iteration of my webjob, it won't move the file. It doesn't threw any exception. It just don't move the file.

I've update the NuGet package WinSCP to version 5.15.2. and I use the .Net framework 4.6.1.

```
public void SendFileToArchive(string fileName)
{
    _log.DebugFormat("Deleting file on local path.");
    File.Delete($"{_config.LocalPath}\\{fileName}");
    if (!_session.Opened)
    {
       _log.DebugFormat("Session is closed -> Open it.");
        this.OpenSession();
    }
    _log.DebugFormat("Move file.");
    _session.MoveFile($"{fileName}", "Archive/" + fileName);
    if (_session.FileExists(fileName))
    {
        _log.Error("File hasn't be moved");
    }
 }

private void OpenSession()
{
   // Configurer les options de session
   SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
   {
       Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
       HostName = _config.FtpUrl,
       UserName = _config.FtpLogin,
       Password = _config.FtpPwd,
       SshHostKeyFingerprint = _config.SshHostKeyFingerprint,
    };
    sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "0");
    _session = new Session();
    // Connecter
    _session.Open(sessionOptions);
}
```

I expect the file to be moved or at least that the process throw an exception.
Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong ?

I can try the check on the existance of the file in destination before move it but in my use case I would be very suprise if that's the cause. Because I checked manually after having error and the file existed only in the source path.

For the openSession, i haven't send you all the code but I call that method in my constructor (used only once in my webjob) or when I check that the session is closed in my move method(I added that part for checking the state of the connexion when I saw that the move part didn't work).

And of course I have a dispose method called when I have done all the process :

```
public void DisposeSession()
{
    if (this._session.Opened)
    {
        this._session.Close();
    }

    this._session.Dispose();
}
```

Here is the log:

```
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Listing file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 44, Number: 5639
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 26, Number: 5380
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Discarding reserved response
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 54, Number: 5639
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json;-;1203;2019-05-23T23:01:40.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.420 Script: -rwxrwxrwx   0 root     root          1203 May 23 23:01:40 2019 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 Script: stat -- "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json"
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 Listing file "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 52, Number: 5895
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 54, Number: 5895
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json;-;1203;2019-05-23T23:01:40.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.482 Script: -rwxrwxrwx   0 root     root          1203 May 23 23:01:40 2019 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Script: mv "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json" "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json"
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Listing file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 44, Number: 6151
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 54, Number: 6151
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json;-;1203;2019-05-23T23:01:40.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Moving file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json" to "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 87, Number: 6418
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 26, Number: 6418
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Status code: 0
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Script: FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 Script: stat -- "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json"
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 Listing file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 44, Number: 6663
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 54, Number: 6663
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json;-;1203;2019-05-23T23:01:40.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.624 Script: -rwxrwxrwx   0 root     root          1203 May 23 23:01:40 2019 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json
```

Does it help ?

Comment: Session log file please! (`Session.SessionLogPath`)

Comment: No I've asked for session log.

Comment: ok sorry. I will try to retrieve it when the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to move a file on the remote server (your are also deleting a local file in the method).

You are creating a new `Session` each time you call `OpenSession()` - without closing/disposing the old one. You should only create the session once in the constructor. This could be an issue.

Furthermore, a remote file cannot be moved if the destination already exist - you have no check for this but you might handle some other way.

Consider if you need `sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "0");`

You might find some additional information in the Session log.

I've made a class for testing based on your code. It works works for me - also for repeated calls:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using WinSCP;

namespace WinSCPTest
{
    public class SftpRemoteMoveTester
    {
        const char SftpDirectorySeparatorChar = '/';

        static readonly SessionOptions SessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = SftpConfig.HostName,
            UserName = SftpConfig.UserName,
            Password = SftpConfig.Password,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = SftpConfig.SshHostKeyFingerprint,
        };

        Session _sftpSession;

        public SftpUploadTester()
        {
            _sftpSession = new Session();
        }

        public void MoveRemoteFile(
            string remoteSourceDirectoryPath,
            string fileName,
            string remoteDestinationDirectoryPath)
        {
            var remoteSourceFilePath = CombineSftpPath(remoteSourceDirectoryPath, fileName);
            var remoteDestinationFilePath = CombineSftpPath(remoteDestinationDirectoryPath, fileName);

            OpenSessionIfNeeded();

            if (!_sftpSession.FileExists(remoteSourceFilePath))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Remote source file does not exists -> return");
                return;
            }

            if (_sftpSession.FileExists(remoteDestinationFilePath))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Remote destination file already exists -> return");
                return;
            }

            _sftpSession.MoveFile(remoteSourceFilePath, remoteDestinationFilePath);

            if (_sftpSession.FileExists(remoteSourceFilePath))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File hasn't be moved from source dir");
            }

            if (_sftpSession.FileExists(remoteSourceFilePath))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File doesn't exists in destination dir");
            }
        }

        public void OpenSessionIfNeeded()
        {
            if (!_sftpSession.Opened)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Session is closed -> Open it.");
                _sftpSession.Open(SessionOptions);
            }
        }

        string CombineSftpPath(params string[] parts)
        {
            return Path.Combine(parts)
                .Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, SftpDirectorySeparatorChar);
        }
    }
}
```

The example does not include any disposal of `_sftpSession` which you might want to add.

Comment: Hi Ulric,
Thx for replying.

Answer (score 0):

```
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Script: mv "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json" "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json"
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Listing file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.561 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 44, Number: 6151
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 54, Number: 6151
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json;-;1203;2019-05-23T23:01:40.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Moving file "FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json" to "Archive/FILETOMOVE_20190524_010139.json".
> 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 87, Number: 6418
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 26, Number: 6418
< 2019-06-05 15:21:21.577 Status code: 0
```

As you can see in the log, the server does not report any error. It return status code 0, indicating a success. So if the file does not move, it's server's fault.